# Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password while using dblink

Tags: postgresql

I want to do some cross database references in my application. Briefly, i have two databases called meta and op. I want to do some select query from meta to a table in op database like below but getting the below error. I tried with password and without password. by the way `caixa` user is a non-super user and my target server (`op` db server is having MD5 authentication mode.)

```
meta=> select * from dblink('dbname=op password=caixa','SELECT op_col from op_table') AS t(op_col varchar);
```

> ERROR:  password is required
>
> DETAIL:  Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password.
>
> HINT:  Target server's authentication method must be changed.

What the HINT in the above error message suggests? do i need to change the server's auth mode? Without changing the server's auth mode (MD5) can't i run the above query?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html):

> Only superusers may use dblink_connect to create
>   non-password-authenticated connections. If non-superusers need this
>   capability, use **dblink_connect_u** instead.

and

> dblink_connect_u() is identical to dblink_connect(), except that it
>   will allow non-superusers to connect using any authentication method.

That means your [`dblink`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink.html) call is using [`dblink_connect`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html) implicitly. Use [`dblink_connect_u`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-connect-u.html) instead or change your auth method to e.g. md5.

Note that you also need grant execute privilege to `caixa` role, for example by:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION dblink_connect_u(text) TO caixa;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION dblink_connect_u(text, text) TO caixa;
```

Working example (after `GRANT`):

```
meta=> SELECT dblink_connect_u('conn1', 'dbname=op');
meta=> SELECT * FROM dblink('conn1','SELECT op_col from op_table')
            AS t(op_col varchar);
 op_col 
--------
 aaa
 bbb
 ccc
(3 rows)
meta=> SELECT dblink_disconnect('conn1');
```

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry for slightly misleading answer. Of course you **don't** need `dblink_connect_u` for md5 authenticated
connection. There is one possibility I see. PostgreSQL has **two different** connection types: **host** and **local**.

Running:

`psql -h localhost ..`

incorporates host connection, but

`dblink_connect('mycon','dbname=vchitta_op user=caixa password=caixa');`

uses **local** type, so if you have non-password method for local connection (for example ident method or trust), then it returns

```
ERROR:  password is required
DETAIL:  Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password.
HINT:  Target server's authentication method must be changed.
```

Check

`dblink_connect('mycon','hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=vchitta_op user=caixa password=caixa')`

for **host** connection. For clarity if possible please post your `pg_hba.conf`.

I also checked what about `CONNECT` privilege on `vchitta_op` DB, but error message is different:

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE vchitta_op FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE vchitta_op FROM caixa;

SELECT dblink_connect('mycon','dbname=vchitta_op user=caixa password=caixa');
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  FATAL:  permission denied for database "vchitta_op"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Comment: No use, i tried dblink_connect_u too..below is the output `vchitta_meta=> select dblink_connect_u('mycon','dbname=vchitta_op'); ERROR: password is required DETAIL: Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string.`

Comment: @vchitta: Check `select dblink_connect('mycon','dbname=vchitta_op user=caixa password=yourpass');` Futhermore you don't need whole `dblink_connect_u` approach if you have md5 already.

Comment: This is my resutl when i tried as you suggested:                                                         `-bash-3.2$ psql -h localhost -d vchitta_meta -U postgres
vchitta_meta=# grant execute on function dblink_connect_u(text) to caixa;
GRANT
vchitta_meta=# grant execute on function dblink_connect_u(text,text) to caixa;
GRANT
vchitta_meta=# \q

-bash-3.2$ psql -h localhost -d vchitta_meta -U caixa

vchitta_meta=> select dblink_connect_u('conn1','dbname=vchitta_op');
**ERROR:  password is required
DETAIL:  Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string.**`

Comment: This time the error slightly changed. <br> `vchitta_meta=> select dblink_connect('mycon','dbname=vchitta_op user=caixa password=caixa');
ERROR:  password is required
<b>DETAIL:  Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password.<b>
HINT:  Target server's authentication method must be changed.`

Comment: infact it is not a new error, it is the one from the beginning.

Comment: Any thoughts? `caixa` user is missing any roles/privileges?

Comment: do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, i have given connect permissions for caixa user on vchitta_op, (infact i have given All permissions) then i am able to do this without even hostaddr. by the way can't i mentiond hostname not the hostaddr? Thanks for your great research. it is very much useful. Thanks once again.

Comment: vchitta: it changed because you granted permission to `dblink_connect_u`, but instead called `dblink_connect` - two different functions

Answer (score 5):

There's a workaround that did the trick for me. Non-superusers can execute functions with privileges of a superuser if "SECURITY DEFINER" option is set.
( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html )

That means you can create a function (with superuser owner and SECURITY DEFINER option) that does cross-database manipulation (using *dblink()* without password) and execute it under non-superuser

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar but a different issue. I have two servers with identical postgres.conf and pg_hba.conf. However one on version 9.2.3 and one on 9.2.4

## 9.2.3

pg_hba.conf has

```
    local   all     dblinkuser      trust
```

then I connect to database using any ordinary user

```
    theater_map=# select dblink_connect('dbname=TheaterDB user=dblinkuser password=dbl123');
    dblink_connect 
    ----------------
    OK
    (1 row)
```

### success in connection.

## 9.2.4

my pg_hba.conf has the same entry as above

```
    theater_map=> select dblink_connect('dbname=TheaterDB user=dblinkuser password=dbl123');
    ERROR:  password is required
    DETAIL:  Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password.
    HINT:  Target server's authentication method must be changed.
```

NOW 
I change my pg_hba.conf on 9.2.4 as below

```
    local   all     dblinkuser      md5
```

and restart postgres

```
    theater_map=> select dblink_connect('dbname=TheaterDB user=dblinkuser password=dbl123');
    dblink_connect 
    ----------------
   OK
   (1 row)
```

---

I Checked the change log between versions 9.2.3 and 9.2.4 but could not find any details.

*note: changing auth method from trust to md5 on 9.2.3 does not make any difference and still works.*

Answer (score 1):

I found this question googling for same error message, though I use fdw extension rather than db_link. Following steps helped to fix my problem:

- find user has no password and set it on - `alter user myuser with password 'mypassword'`
- find authentication method is `trust` and set it to `md5` - `vim /var/lib/postgresql/data_/pg_hba.conf`
- reload `pg_hba.conf` - `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` from psql (log out and log in to verify password is required)
- (optionally try access from remote machine, db browser etc.)
- setup foreign server and its user mapping - `CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER SERVER myserver OPTIONS (user 'myuser', password 'mypassword');`

Answer (score 0):

**PostgreSQL 11.10**

```
SELECT ext.column1 from
dblink('hostaddr=192.192.192.192 dbname=yourDbname user=yourUsername password=yourpass',
'select a."column1" from "Table1" a where a."column2"=2')
as ext(column1 text)
```

Comment: No any explanations.

Comment: seeing the hostaddr actually helped me. although the answer shall have explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add new user as:
*ALTER USER test WITH SUPERUSER ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'testpassword';*

IN pg_hba.conf add line:
*host    database_name          test            0.0.0.0/0  md5*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason in my case was a wrong password when creating user mapping.
the mapping should be like:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR myuser SERVER "FS_postgres_fdw_myserver_mydatabase"
    OPTIONS ("user" 'myuser', password 'mypassword');
```