# PostgreSQL RDS avoid hard coding the connection password when using dblink_connect()

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds, plpgsql

I have an AWS RDS instance of PostgreSQL in which I need to execute an `SQL` statement within a function using `dblink_connect(text)` and `dblink_exec(text)` while logged in with the `postgres` role (that I created).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION application.create_tenant_schemas(first integer, last integer) RETURNS void AS
DECLARE
  tenant VARCHAR;
  sql VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  FOR index IN first..last LOOP
    tenant := 'tenant_' || to_char(index, 'FM00000');

    sql := 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || quote_ident(tenant);
    RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;

    PERFORM dblink_connect('dbname=application user=postgres');
    PERFORM dblink_exec(sql);
    PERFORM dblink_disconnect();

  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The `dblink_exec()` is producing the following error messages:

```
[2F003] ERROR: password is required
Detail: Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string.
Where: SQL statement "SELECT dblink_connect('dbname=application user=postgres')"
```

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031737/non-superuser-cannot-connect-if-the-server-does-not-request-a-password-while-usi) that suggested using `dblink_connect_u(text)`. When I tried this I got the following error messages:

```
[42501] ERROR: permission denied for function dblink_connect_u
Where: SQL statement "SELECT dblink_connect_u('dbname=application user=postgres')"
```

On AWS how can I give the user that created the RDS instance permission to execute function `dblink_connect_u()`? I tried the following without success:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION dblink_connect_u(text) TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION dblink_connect_u(text, text) TO postgres;
```

It seems my `postgres` user needs `superuser` permissions to which I apparently cannot have on AWS.

I also played with using `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` (on Windows) to provide the password for `dblink_connect(text)` but `dblink_connect(text)` apparently ignores this file.

I was able to use a hard coded the password string to call `dblink_connect(text)` as follows:

```
PERFORM "pascal"."dblink_connect_u"('dbname=pascal user=postgres password=secret');
```

...ultimately, this is not an acceptable solution due to the hard coding of the password.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to get RDS PostgreSQL to either use the password file or allow me to `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION dblink_connect_u(text)` or is there another alternative that I haven't come across?

**UPDATE**

Links to PostgreSQL documentation for trying to set up a foreign data wrapper / server in which to store the password for the user that's executing `dblink_connect(text)`

[CREATE SERVER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createserver.html)

[CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html)

[CREATE USER MAPPING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createusermapping.html)

**CONCLUSION**

```
CREATE SERVER "password_server" FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER "dblink_fdw"
OPTIONS (dbname 'application');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR "postgres"
SERVER "password_server"
OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'pa55VV0&d');
```

... different source file ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION application.create_tenant_schemas(first integer, last integer) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  tenant VARCHAR;
  sql VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  FOR index IN first..last LOOP
    tenant := 'tenant_' || to_char(index, 'FM00000');

    sql := 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || quote_ident(tenant);
    RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;

    PERFORM "dblink_connect"('password_server');
    PERFORM "dblink_exec"(sql);
    PERFORM "dblink_disconnect"();
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create user mapping:

1. `create server application_srv foreign data wrapper dblink_fdw OPTIONS (...`;
2. `create user mapping FOR app_user SERVER application_srv OPTIONS (user 'user_to_connect', password 'password goes here');`
3. use `application_srv` in dblink connection name:

.

```
t# select * from dblink('application_srv','select max(t) from t') as t(m timestamp(0));
          m
---------------------
 2017-06-13 11:41:05
(1 row)
```

now the password will be displayed plain text in `pg_user_mappings` (`pg_user_mapping` should be not selectable for anyone in RDS), but the actual pass will be displayed only to `rds_superuser`

Comment: Nice idea. Unfortunately it seems that in order to do the `CREATE SERVER` command I need to define a `FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER` and to define the `FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER` I need to have superuser privileges which puts me back where I started...

Comment: no - I gave this solution from my tollbox. this is how I do it on RDS. please disclose the statement and error

Comment: My mistake. I needed to install the `dblink` extension in the database in which I was trying to add the `FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER` - I was experimenting in a database that did not have the `dblink` extension installed...

Comment: My calls are working - but when I create a do the `CREATE SCHEMA` the schema is being created in the wrong database - how do I set or change the database for the user mapping? (there isn't an option for `dblink` to pass the database name to connect)

Comment: `create server application_srv foreign data wrapper dblink_fdw OPTIONS (dbname 'a')` will create a server to connect to database name 'a'