# Create db_link to the same Database in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, dblink

We do have a requirement to create a db_link(Database link) have to refer to the same database.

When I am looking at the code in the function. It is some how like this.

```
perform dblink_connect(cn,'loopback'::text);
   cn is the connection name;
```

I verified if there are any foreign servers with the name loopback by using this query. But, no luck

```
select 
    srvname as name, 
    srvowner::regrole as owner, 
    fdwname as wrapper, 
    srvoptions as options
from pg_foreign_server
join pg_foreign_data_wrapper w on w.oid = srvfdw;
```

I suspect that loopback refers to the same database.

When I execute the Function, I am receiving the below error

```
**Error:password is required**
```

I verified the `db_link extension it's there and dblink_fdw is also there`

```
Environment:Postgres RDS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call should look like this:

```
PERFORM dblink_connect(cn, 'host=loopback user=...');
```

This is a normal libpq connect string; see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) for details.

It would be smarter to use the IP addresses in the connection string, like

```
host=127.0.0.1 user=...
```

or to use domain socket connections, like this

```
host=/var/run/postgresql user=...
```

(that is, if your `unix_socket_directories` contains this directory).

`pg_hba.conf` should contain lines like

```
# lockal socket connections
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

If you want password authentications, use `md5` instead of `trust` and supply a password in the connection string.

I have never heard of dblink_fdw …

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe, I am not aware of loopback connections. Can you please post a link that explains the dblink loopback.
How to supply password to the loopback connection?

Comment: So, Do I need to create foreign Server with the name of loopback to refer to the same database?
Notes:
-dblink_fdw Foreign Data Wrapper is created automatically  when we 
     CREATE EXTESION DBLINK;
-To avoid hardcoding the password
 we will create foreign server
reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663478/postgresql-rds-avoid-hard-coding-the-connection-password-when-using-dblink-conne

Comment: You don't need a FDW. `loopback` is a DNS hostname for the machine itself. The PostgreSQL documentation says nothing about a dblink_fdw.

Comment: I'm getting error that hostname cannot be found to be honest. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Then use the IP address 127.0.0.1